# Can I suppress F# compiler making copy of function in IL code?

Tags: reflection, f#, compiler-construction

I want to create a JIT GPU compiler. You give an F# function, and we JIT compile it. The key of JIT compiling is to be able to cache the compiling result. I tried to use the `MethodInfo` as the caching key, but it won't work. It seems that F# compiler will make a copy of the function instead of referencing the origin function. Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

Here is a test code, ideally, it should be just compiled twice, but it did it 4 times.

```
let compileGpuCode (m:MethodInfo) =
    printfn "JIT compiling..."
    printfn "Type  : %A" m.ReflectedType
    printfn "Method: %A" m
    printfn ""
    "fake gpu code"

let gpuCodeCache = ConcurrentDictionary<MethodInfo, string>()

let launchGpu (func:int -> int -> int) =
    let m = func.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke", [| typeof<int>; typeof<int> |])
    let gpuCode = gpuCodeCache.GetOrAdd(m, compileGpuCode)
    // launch gpuCode
    ()

let myGpuCode (a:int) (b:int) = a + 2 * b

[<Test>]
let testFSFuncReflection() =
    launchGpu (+)
    launchGpu (+)
    launchGpu myGpuCode
    launchGpu myGpuCode
```

Here is the output:

```
JIT compiling...
Type  : AleaTest.FS.Lab.Experiments+testFSFuncReflection@50
Method: Int32 Invoke(Int32, Int32)

JIT compiling...
Type  : AleaTest.FS.Lab.Experiments+testFSFuncReflection@51-1
Method: Int32 Invoke(Int32, Int32)

JIT compiling...
Type  : AleaTest.FS.Lab.Experiments+testFSFuncReflection@52-2
Method: Int32 Invoke(Int32, Int32)

JIT compiling...
Type  : AleaTest.FS.Lab.Experiments+testFSFuncReflection@53-3
Method: Int32 Invoke(Int32, Int32)
```

Comment: Every time you pass `myGpuCode`, you create a new delegate to it. Each of them is a different function (closure) that invokes the underlying function. As far as I know, there's no simple way to preserve the identity of the input function.

Comment: @Luaan I understand, if you create curry function there, it is fine and reasonable to create a new delegate (closure) to it. But if it is just referencing the function, it would be good that there are some optimization, to reference instead of making a new copy. In C#, the delegate type will reference the origin method, but of course the lambda function in C# , it will also create a new method for the closure.

Comment: In C#, you will get a delegate that wraps the underlying method, yes; but it's not a guarantee, and it still doesn't preserve the identity when you have a closure. If you used the analogous code in C#, it would work while you kept both `launchGpu(() => myGpuCode(...))` in the same class, but break as soon as you used two classes (because you'd again get two separate methods that invoke the wrapped function). I'm afraid you're deep in undefined territory here, and if you find a solution, it will likely break in the future with changes to the F# compiler or the .NET runtime.

Comment: But mind you, I might be missing something obvious - I'm certainly no expert on F# :) Perhaps using quotations would work better?

Comment: A better approach would be to compile quotations. Higher level of code - easier to compile, and you can solve the identity problem. Have you looked at Alea or [other available options](http://fsharp.org/use/gpu/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The F# compiler treats your code more as something like this:

```
launchGpu (fun a b -> myGpuCode a b)
launchGpu (fun a b -> myGpuCode a b)
```

When compiling this, it will generate a new class to represent the function on each of the lines. If you wrote your test as follows:

```
let f = myGpuCode
launchGpu f
launchGpu f
```

... it would generate just one class (for the one place where the function is referenced) and then share the same type in both of the calls - so this would work.

In this example, the compiler actually inlines `myGpuCode` because it is too short, but if you make it more complex, then it generates very simple `Invoke` function in both of the classes:

```
ldarg.1
ldarg.2
call int32 Test::myGpuCode(int32, int32)
ret
```

I'm sure there is a plenty of caveats, but you could just check if the body of the generated class contains the same IL and uses that as your key instead. Once you have the `Invoke` method, you can get the IL body using the following:

```
let m = func.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke", [| typeof<int>; typeof<int> |])
let body = m.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()
```

This will be the same for both of the classes - ideally, you could also analyze this to figure out if the code is just calling some other method.